# Permanent Highlighting in AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex

I want to highlight text regions in my Emacs/AUCTeX/LaTeX document in a "textmarker style". Furthermore, the highlighting should save permanently. These features are provided by `highlight.el` and enriched-mode, which [works fine with plain text file](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/?action=browse;oldid=HighLight;id=HighlightLibrary#toc4).

However, this doesn't work for LaTeX files `*.tex`, where I could not select text properties any more.

How can I combine text highlighting with AUCTeX?

Answer (score 1):

Using `enriched-mode` won't work since it actually saves the file in a different format—one that would prevent `latex` from working.  Try <kbd>M-x</kbd><kbd>find-file-literally</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>path/to/enriched/mode/file</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> and you will see something like

```
Content-Type: text/enriched Text-Width: 70
<x-color><param>grey45</param>(</x-color><x-color><param>red4</param>defun</x-color>
<x-color><param>red4</param>hlt-region-or-buffer-limits</x-color>
<x-color><param>grey45</param>()</x-color>
<x-color><param>royalblue4</param>"Return the start and end of the
region as a list, smallest first.  If the region is empty or not
active, then bob and eob are used."</x-color>
<x-color><param>grey45</param>(</x-color><x-color><param>red4</param>if</x-color>
...
```

If you want things highlighted systematically it can probably be done with `font-lock-add-keywords`, but if it's entirely arbitrary you would have to write a system that saves another file containing markers and then reads them in on file open and performs the highlighting.  It's not impossible but as far as I know, noone has done it yet.  See this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903137/emacs-persistent-highlighting-of-a-region) question.

The question I think is really, what are you trying to accomplish.  If it's drawing attention to an area that needs help for example then maybe adding a comment `% TODO: description` together with something like [fic-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/fic-mode.el) (which I have never used) would be the best option.  With a little more work you could even have it highlight the entire next sentence or something.